# Clearing data before reading a new line

Tags: c#, string, winforms

I have a considerable number of strings in my application that need to be cleared each time I get new data from my source. I'd like to use something akin to `string.Empty`, but I am unsure of how to implement this. Ideally, I'd also like to do this only once, rather than for each separate string.

Pseudo-code:

```
foreach (string in application)
{
    this.empty
}
```

Am I thinking on the right track?

Some of my code is as follows:
**classtoinstantiate**

```
public string Str1;
private string str1 {get {return Str1;}}
public void DoStuff()
{
    doStuff();
}
private void doStuff()
{
    //dostuff
}
```

And **Form1.cs**

```
classtoinstantiate class1 = new classtoinstantiate();
class.DoStuff();
//I would like to then clear the *public* iteration of string Str1 here, 
                                                      //before I DoStuff() again.
```

Comment: How are you storing the strings?

Comment: Ah deleted my answear didnt understand at first what you wanted, you have to "empty" each string on its own. Just put them all into a List and iterate through that list and do stringList[a] = "";

Comment: show some actual code

Comment: @RufusL They are in a sub-class. The main class instantiates the sub-class, and thus the strings. There is also more than one class.

Comment: @Vajura if he want do the same as u said, the code he posted will work

Comment: If you give us an example it is easier to help. Are they string properties? Are they fields? Do they all belong to one class / instance?

Comment: @Selman22 I came here for advice on formulating that code, if I knew what I were creating I would not have needed to ask this question.

Comment: I suggest to put all your strings in to a class and dispose the object if you get new data

Comment: @Vallabha so setting my class to null and then re-instantiating it prior to getting new data?

Comment: Create a `Dictionary` for a field of your class and define your string like a variable with name in it and when you decide to clear all these variable, you can easily do this... for example, instead `string S = "EXAMPLE";` <=> `D.add("S","EXAMPLE");`

Comment: I mean, are you storing all the strings in a public list property of the class? Do you have a bunch of different properties, that happen to be of type string, that you want to set to empty (or null?). Please give a more concrete example of what you want.

Comment: Is there any reason you have to clear the strings and not just recreate the instances?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's the basic OOP concept: construct object when you need it, destroy at the end. Constructing part always deals with *default* values, which is exactly what you need.

For managed objects (`string`) simply create a new instance of a class holding all data what has to be *reset* (*cleared*):

```
class SomeDataStorage
{
    // default is null
    public string Data1 {get; set;}

    private string _data2 = "default value";
    public string Data2 { get {return _data2;} set {_data2 = value;}}
}
```

Then you construct this object when you need it

```
foreach (string in application)
{
    var data = new SomeDataStorage(); // default values
    ...
}
```

It will be auto*magically* destroyed when going out of scope (leaving `{ }` or exiting function).

For unmanaged objects, implement `IDisposable` and consider to use `using() { }` often to auto-dispose.

You can have application-wide instance of `SomeDataStorage`. Simply assign a new object (construct new instance) to reset values to default.

To make it even more clear:

```
class App
{
    public SomeDataStorage MyData;

    public App()
    {
        Reset();
    }

    // call this when you need to init for the first time or simply reset to default
    public void Reset()
    {
        MyData = new SomeDataStorage();
    }
}
```

Comment: I added an edit to give a brief example of how my application is created. Does this help?

Comment: The point is you do not need to *clear* anything. Simply use *new instance* of data holder every time when you want data to be *reset*. It is memory-wasteful (because every time you create a new instance, but we have garbage collector to stop thinking `c++`-way, taking too much care for each allocate); performance-wise it is the nearly same as calling a method, which will go through all properties and set their values to default. And the real gain is.. you don't have to write such method.

Answer (score 2):

`String.Empty` represents a not null empty string.
If you want to clear a large amount of data (string/non string) you can encapsulate all of the variables in one class and create a Clean() method that goes through all the variables and clears them or instantiate that class when you need a fresh copy when you set the default values in the constructor.

The use of class.Empty is from what I understand to have a well defined instance of what is an empty instance.

Answer (score 2):

Given your comments I get the feeling that you only want to clear the strings, have a look at this `C#` like pseudo code:

```
public void ClearString(IEnumerable<object> stuffToClear)
{
  // go through all the objects to clear
  foreach (var item in stuffToClear)
  {
    // get the properties to clear
    var props = from prop in item.GetType().GetProperties()
                where prop.PropertyType == typeof(string) // or another type or filter
                select prop;
    for (var p in props)
    {
      // clear it
      p.SetValue(item, string.Empty);
    }
  }
}
```

Not that I'm writing this in freehand, all calls will surely not be correct.

Comment: This is pretty much what I was after (I think). Many thanks.

I'll update it once I've tested it out, if you like.

Comment: This is a bad practice IMHO

Comment: @Amorphis I totally agree, but we don't know the original scenario, and this will solve the issue. But a redesign somewhere else would have been better.

Comment: here every string will be set to empty one by one. i don't think it will be useful because this will be as same the  pseudo code posted

Comment: I have added an example of how my application is created. Does this assist?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to put all your strings in to a class and dispose the object if you get new data

Answer (score 0):

```
public class StringCollection
{
    public string StringProp1 { get; set; }
    public string StringProp2 { get; set; }
    public string StringProp3 { get; set; }
    public string StringProp4 { get; set; }

    // .... more properties here

    // this property won't be touched when clearing
    public int SomeOtherProperty{ get; set; }

    public void ClearStrings()
        {
            // returns all public properties
           foreach (var prop in this.GetType().GetProperties())
        {
            // "clear" only properties of type String and those that have a public setter
            if (prop.PropertyType == typeof(string) && prop.CanWrite) 
                prop.SetValue(this, string.Empty, null); // <- "clear" value of the property 
        }
    }
```

or, in a more general manner - use extension methods:

```
 public class StringCollection
    {
        public string StringProp1 { get; set; }
        public string StringProp2 { get; set; }
        public string StringProp3 { get; set; }
        public string StringProp4 { get; set; }

        public int SomeOtherProperty { get; set; }
    }


    public class SomeOtherClass
    {
        public string a1 { get; set; }
        public string a2 { get; set; }
        public string a3 { get; set; }

        public DateTime d1 { get; set; }
        public int SomeOtherProperty { get; set; }
    }

    public static class MyExtensions
    {
        public static void ClearStrings(this Object obj)
        {
            // returns all public properties
            foreach (var prop in obj.GetType().GetProperties())
            {
                // "clear" only properties of type String and those that have a public setter
                if (prop.PropertyType == typeof(string) && prop.CanWrite)
                    prop.SetValue(obj, string.Empty, null); // <- "clear" value of the property 
            }
        }
    }
```

use the code:

```
        StringCollection scol2 = new StringCollection();
        // ... do soemthing
        scol2.ClearStrings();

        SomeOtherClass obj = new SomeOtherClass();
        // ... do something
        obj.ClearStrings();
```